# WPF: How to get the event when one FrameworkElement comes in contact with other FrameworkElement

Tags: c#, wpf, events, drag-and-drop, collision-detection

I am developing a small application with images and trash box icon on right hand bottom.

I have multiple images floating in the main window, and using mouse I can move image from one corner to other corner of window, left, right, top and bottom.

I can't figure out how do I catch an event when a image touches and panel (with trash box image), in the right hand corner.

Does anybody knows which event or handler to listen? This is not a drag and drop case since my images are floating so no point using drag and drop.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b1cf3a53-0389-4503-b588-d05d362feeb8) (MSDN), you could listen to an event fired when your image moves, and get `Rect`s representing the trash box and the image, then use the `IntersectsWith()` method to detect if they are "touching".

Other than that, there are the [UIElement events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement_events%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) DragEnter, DragOver, and Drop (as well as their Preview___ counterparts) which might fit the bill. However, those are part of drag-and-drop. I'm *not* convinced that drag-and-drop is *not* appropriate in this situation. It sounds like drag and drop to me.